# Minkowski Set Addition

Tags: summation, rational-numbers

What is the Minkowski sum of Q to itself, where Q is the set of all rational numbers?

I can't find a way to solve this with freshman knowledge.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}+\mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Q}$. Since $0 \in \mathbb{Q}$ clearly $ \mathbb{Q} \subset  \mathbb{Q}+ \mathbb{Q}$ and if $q,r \in  \mathbb{Q}$ then clearly $q+r \in  \mathbb{Q}$ hence $\mathbb{Q}+\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Why is it not {2*m/n : m,n belong to Z, n!=0} ?

Comment: Because set addition is defined as $A+B=\{a+b| a \in A, b\in B\}$. So, $A+A$ is not $2A$. Note that we must have $2A \subset A+A$ but not the other way around. For example, take $A = \{0,1\}$ then $A+A =\{0,1,2\}$ not $\{0,2\}$.

Comment: I think I got it. So, if we add [0,1]+[2,3] for example, we get [2,4]?

Comment: Yes, but make sure you understand why $A+A \neq 2A$ in this context.

Comment: Because we add every element of the first set to each one of the elements of the other set, but in this case the first and the other set are the same (A).

Comment: Well, it is because when you are adding $A+A$ you don't pick just one $a\in A$ and compute $2a$, instead you pick different $a_1,a_2 \in A$ and compute $a_1+a_2$.

Comment: I get that, but I cannot compute the sum of Z+(0,1).

Comment: Why not, you will get $...\cup (-1,0) \cup (0,1) \cup (1,2) \cup...$. So basically, $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$!

Comment: As long as addition is defined for elements of $A,B$ then $A+B$ makes sense.

Comment: So, is Q+R\Q=R and why?

Comment: How would you write $0$ as a sum of a rational and an irrational?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be $\mathbb{Q}$ since $$\frac{m}{n}+\frac{m'}{n'}$$ is rational for all nonzero integers $n,n'$ and all integers $m,m'$?

Answer (score 0):

The sum of tow rationals is rational, so $$\mathbb{Q}+\mathbb{Q}\subseteq \mathbb{Q}$$  To show the opposite containment, we need to show that any rational can be expressed as the sum of two rationals.  Take one of the two rationals to be $0.$